# Confused about order in Opposite Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am facing confusion in the "order of multiplication" regarding the opposite algebra $B^o$ in the following working:

Define a right $B^o$-module $M_\phi$ where $M_\phi=M$ via $m\cdot b=m\phi(b)$.

Background information: $B$ is a $F$-algebra. $M$ is a $F$-vector space. $\phi$ is a $F$-algebra homomorphism from $B$ to $\text{End}_F(M)$.

> Puzzling is the following working:
>
> $\begin{align*}(m\cdot b_1)\cdot b_2&=(m\phi(b_1))\cdot b_2\\
> &=m\phi(b_2)\phi(b_1)\\
> &=m\phi(b_2b_1)\\
> &=m\cdot (b_1b_2)
> \end{align*}$

To be precise, I don't get the switching between $b_2b_1$ and $b_1b_2$. (Roughly speaking, I do know multiplication in $B^o$ is "twisted" but I don't understand it precisely in this context).

Comment: How do you define $m\phi(b)$ ?

Comment: @Unfortunately there is no definition. $\phi(b)\in\text{End}_F(M)$ so all we know is it acts on $M$ (from the right).

Answer (score 3):

If you start from $\phi: B\to End_F(M)$ then $M$ is a left $B$-module, by $b\cdot m = \phi(b)(m)$.

Then by definition $M$ is a right $B^o$-module, because in general a structure of right $A$-module on $X$ is a morphism $A^o\to End(X)$, so here $\phi: B=B^{oo}\to End_F(M)$.

The definition of the right action is then $m\cdot b^o = b\cdot m = \phi(b)(m)$ (where I write $b^o$ when I see $b\in B$ as an element of $B^o$, which clarifies things a bit).

So $(m\cdot b_1^o)\cdot b_2^o = \phi(b_1)(m)\cdot b_2^o = \phi(b_2)\circ \phi(b_1)(m) = \phi(b_2b_1)(m) = m\cdot (b_2b_1)^o = m\cdot (b_1^ob_2^o)$.

So this is indeed a right action of $B^o$, since a right action satisfies $(m\cdot x)\cdot y = m\cdot (xy)$.